# How to transpose/pivot time series data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table that is in such form:

| Day | Group | Signal | T0 | T1 | ... | T23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Voltage | L1 | 230.0 | 229.5 | ... | 231.2 |
| 2022-01-01 | Voltage | L2 | 225.4 | 231.2 | ... | 230.3 |

Every day is split into 24 hours and values are stored into columns T0-T23.

How can I get to the desired result, which is this:

| Date | Time | Group | Signal | SignalValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 00:00 | Voltage | L1 | 230.0 |
| 2022-01-01 | 01:00 | Voltage | L1 | 229.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 2022-01-01 | 23:00 | Voltage | L2 | 230.3 |

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the SQL tag you added and read the description in the pop-up window about what you need to provide when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what your DBMS is but the following UNPIVOT example will work in SQL Server, YMMV in other products

```
SELECT  [Day],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),TIMEFROMPARTS(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day)-1,0,0,0,0),108) AS [Time],
        [Group],
        Signal,
        Val
FROM    (
            SELECT  [Day],
                    [Group],
                    Signal,
                    T0,
                    T1,
                    T23
            FROM    MyData
        ) AS p
        UNPIVOT 
        (
            Val FOR Times IN (T0,T1,T23)
        ) AS t
ORDER BY [Day],
         [Group],
         Signal
```

Comment: Sorry, M$ SQL Server (on Azure) is my DBMS. 
As for your query, thank you, it seems to be close, but I get an empty table as result. 
When I tried to find the error I did the select until UNPIVOT and the column for Time crashes after 24 rows. If I understand correctly, you used ROW_NUMBER to get the time, but row numbers can go over 24. The column name (T0 - T23) should somehow be used to get the hour of the day.

Comment: I made it work, using
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day)-1)%24)

To get NULL values I also had to use this instead of UNPIVOT:

CROSS APPLY
  (
  VALUES ('T0',T0),('T1',T1),('T2',T2),...('T23',T23))
  )